# Can't download Ubuntu 17.10 image

Tags: 17.10, downloads, iso

I'm having problems trying to download the iso for Ubuntu 17.10 from the official website. It shows a "file incomplete" message right after I click the download button:

[image: Error message]

Although my browser is Chrome, the same behaviour happens with Firefox as well.

Comment: Try downloading the image from a mirror.  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors . I download from my ISP for fastest speed; though I grab the md5sum from the official site to confirm the image/iso is untouched :)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your reply. I've tried with my local mirrors (UK) and even some USA ones but they didn't work. After trying with some random countries it worked and it's now downloading.
Please post it as an answer so I can close the question

Comment: Whether it is an issue of some mirrors or not, this is not a problem of your Ubuntu operating system. It's either your connection or the mirrors themselves. So it's not really on topic here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the image from a mirror.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

I personally download from my ISP for fastest speed; though I always grab the md5sum from the official site, just to confirm the image/iso is untouched :)